# Power BI: Filter a visual with a measure value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a visual from Table A. Now I have a measure which has a numeric output. How can I filter the visual with that measure?
TableA has column Number, Value and Date. The visual shows Value and Date. With the measure I want to filter the Number column dynamically.
For example the output of the measure is 10, then I want to filter the column Number in TableA (for the visual) where all the values are also 10.

I had the idea to make a measure which gives back 1 or 0 when the column meets the criteria. And then add this to the filter panel. But somehow the measure didn't work.

DAX Query
Filter = IF(VALUES(TableA[Number])=[Measure],1,0)
Then I tried to filter this measure on the filter panel with values which have a 1.

I don't want to create a extra measured table for that.

Is that possible? Somehow I didn't find any solution for that in all the forums.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Here some more details

This is how the TableA look like
[image]

This is how the visual looks without filtering (just sums everything up)
[image]

With a "hardcoded" filter of "number" the visual looks like this (what I want to achieve)
[image]

Exactly that filter on the filter pane should be dynamically with a measure.
So sometimes the "number" filter is set to 10 and sometimes it is another number. Also that the visual changes.

I hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer or a workaround.

The DAX filter should look like

```
DAX Filter Query = SUMX (
FILTER (
    TableA,
    TableA[Number] = [Measure]
),
TableA[Value])
```

Then put this "Filter" as new Value to the Y-axis

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DAX Query Filter = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(TableA),
    TableA[Number] = [Measure]
  )
```

Then add `[DAX Query Filter]` as a visual filter set to `is not blank`.

Try also this modified expression:

```
DAX Query Filter = 
  var mValue = CALCULATE([Measure])
  return CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(TableA),
    TableA[Number] = mValue
  )
```

Comment: This somehow does not work, like when I just put the Number column into the filter pane and set it to 10. The results differ.

Comment: So now we go deeper, what does `[Measure]` look like? If you add it to the visual (table) does it show the expected values? Are you able to share sample/mock PBIX?

Comment: Measure is just a number like 10. So instead of showing all the values in the visual, I just want to show the values which have a 10 in the "number" column. The thing is the filter has to be dynamically, that is why I thought I can do it with a DAX measure.
I try to update the Question with some more detailed informations

Comment: The above answer should work for you then. **Ensure** you are adding the new `DAX Query Filter` measure as a visual filter and set it to `is not blank`, as stated in the answer.

Comment: No unfortunately not, the visual still sums everything up

Comment: Can you share a link to your PBIX please (via OneDrive, Google Drive, Drop Box etc...)

Comment: No sry I can't. Company data..

Comment: Then share a screen grab of the what your Filter pane for the visual looks like with this new measure. And share the expression for `[Measure]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question - this should do it:

```
DAX Query Filter = INT(SELECTEDVALUE(TableA[Number])=[Measure])
```

You can also your own formula if you just swap the VALUES-function with SELECTEDVALUE

```
DAX Query Filter 2 = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(TableA[Number])=[Measure],1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work like that. I added more detailed information above.